# How to setup Visual Studio (2022) with CMake and a toolchain targetting non-Windows build?

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2022

We have a project using CMake and a toolchain that targets a non-Windows system (OS-9). This works perfectly fine. Developers have been using Eclipse for developing but when switching to CMake problems arose, since Eclipse is not able to find the system includes, lists search results multiple times (within the build directory, within the source directory etc.) etc. In short, developers are not satisfied with the experience using Eclipse anymore. So we tried to use Visual Studio 2022, since it was announced that it should support CMake quite well.

The first attempts provided good results, using a `CMakePresets.json` Visual Studio is able to switch between `Debug` and `Release` configurations by using a simple dropdown. The configuration and compilation of the project works out of the box.

The IDE is also able to find all includes - even those that come with the customized Clang (`<string>`, `<mqueue.h>` etc.). But the IDE struggles to resolve symbols all over. In the same file, where an `#include <string>` is present and where the IDE is able to find that header file (pressing `F12` on the inclusion leads to the correct file), it cannot resolve `std::string`. The same applies for project files. A CPP file that states `#include "MessageQueueInterface.h"` (where the type called `MessageQueueInterface` is defined) is marked with the error that there is no type called `MessageQueueInterface`, even though the file can be found.

Another problem is the symbol browser, it is always empty, even though the class is correctly interpreted (some files do not have errors).

I am wondering whether I am missing some magic handwaves or whether it is known that CMake support is incomplete within Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: I'm not sure that anything other than Linux is supported as a target https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/get-started-linux-cmake?view=msvc-170

Comment: You are probably missing `intellisenseMode` flag https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-presets-vs?view=msvc-170#select-your-compilers

Comment: Thanks! Adding `intelliSenseMode` and `toolset` helps indeed! Still missing the symbol browser (the document outline), it stays empty.